# proper way to implement dropdowns in ng2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

What is the proper way to implement dropdowns in ng2?  I did some googling but I wasn't finding a lot of consistency.

My search.component.ts has a searchMetadata property which gets set via ngOnInit().

searchMetadata.Authors looks like [{Id=1, Value="Bob Smith"},{Id=2, Value="Mary Jones"}]

The final ng2 dropdown should be something like this:

```
<select #ddlAuthor (change)="updateSearchResults()">
    <option value="1">John Smith</option>
    <option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
    <option value="3">John Denver</option>
</select>
```

What is the proper way to implement ng2 for this in the component.html?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*ngFor` to iterate over an array/collection populate the value and text accordingly. I've updated the answer to simulate a delay of `3000ms` before setting the values to mimic an HTTP API call.

**HTML:**

```html
<select #ddlAuthor (change)="updateSearchResults($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.Id">{{option.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS:**

```
export class App {
  options: any[];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // simulated delay for API call
    Observable
      .of([
        {Id:1, Value:"Bob Smith"},
        {Id:2, Value:"Mary Jones"}
      ]).delay(3000).subscribe(values => {
        this.options = values;
      });
  }

  updateSearchResults($event) {
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XdNceGkeagZ6xywVdgaE?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

**Note:** The array you referenced in your question `[{Id=1, Value="Bob Smith"},{Id=2, Value="Mary Jones"}]` is not valid JavaScript syntax. Objects are structured as `{ key: value }`, it would need be a colon ":" character between the key and value rather than a equal sign "=" like in [C# Object Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer). Having the "=" will cause errors in your Angular application.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<select (change)="updateSearchResults()" #ddlAuthor>
    <option *ngFor="let author of blogSearchMetadata.Authors">{{author.Value}}</option>
</select>
```